# TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable

Tags: python, time

I have some Python code that iterates through all the days between two start dates. The start date is always November 1st and the end date is always May 31st. However, the code iterates through years. My code is as so:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta as td

list1 = [2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013]
list2 = [2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014]


for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
    print "list1 - " + str(x)
    print "list2 - " + str(y)


    d1 = date(x,11,01)
    d2 = date(y,5,31)

    delta = d2 - d1



    for i in range(delta.days + 1):

        time1 =  str(d1 + td(days=i))
        time2 = time1.split("-", 1)[0]
        time3 = time1.split("-", -1)[1]
        time4 = time1.rsplit("-", 1)[-1]

        time2 = int(time2)
        time3 = int(time3)
        time4 = int(time4)

        date = datetime(year=time2, month=time3, day=time4)

...some processing here...
```

This code works fine until the first cycle is completed. It then prints the next two values of 'list1' and 'list2' as 2001 and 2002 to the log, before producing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\newtets\newtets\spiders\test3.py", line 17, in <module>
    d1 = date(x,11,01)
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable
```

It doesn't seem to be resolving the year assigned to the variable 'x' on this second pass through. Can anyone tell me why this is?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is because you are having a variable called `date` that is shadowing imported `datetime.date`. Use a different variable name.

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import date, datetime
>>> date(01,11,01)
datetime.date(1, 11, 1)
>>> date = datetime(year=2014, month=1, day=2)
>>> date(01,11,01)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the following line:

```
date = datetime(year=time2, month=time3, day=time4)
```

is the issue. Here, you are re-defining *date* to have a different value (that can't be called) to the date class (which could be).

On the 'second pass through', it gets to:

```
d1 = date(x,11,01)
```

and *date* isn't what it used to be (it can't be called), and so you get the error.

Maybe change variable name to be something else, e.g. dte?

Comment: This is misleading terminology. You certainly can call a variable; `d = datetime.strptime; d('2014', '%Y')`. For that matter, `date` was _already_ a variable, it's just that it used to name the `date` class, which was callable, and now it names a `datetime` instance, which is not. And if you meant "object" or "instance" or something like that, that doesn't work either; any class can define a `__call__` method, and functions and classes are instances of classes that do exactly that (defined by the language, rather than your code, but otherwise no different).