# rename the pandas Series

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have some wire thing when renaming the pandas Series by the datetime.date

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], name='t')
```

I got `a` is:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
Name: t, dtype: int64
```

Then, I have:

```
ts = pd.Series([pd.Timestamp('2016-05-16'), 
                pd.Timestamp('2016-05-17'), 
                pd.Timestamp('2016-05-18'), 
                pd.Timestamp('2016-05-19')], name='time')
```

with `ts` as:

```
0   2016-05-16
1   2016-05-17
2   2016-05-18
3   2016-05-19
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now, if I do:

```
ts_date = ts.apply(lambda x: x.date())
dates = ts_date.unique()
```

I got `dates` as:

```
array([datetime.date(2016, 5, 16), datetime.date(2016, 5, 17),
       datetime.date(2016, 5, 18), datetime.date(2016, 5, 19)], dtype=object)
```

---

I have two approaches. The wired thing is, if I do the following renaming (approach 1):

```
for one_date in dates:
    a.rename(one_date)
    print one_date, a.name
```

I got:

```
2016-05-16 t
2016-05-17 t
2016-05-18 t
2016-05-19 t
```

But if I do it like this (approach 2):

```
for one_date in dates:
    a = pd.Series(a, name=one_date)
    print one_date, a.name

2016-05-16 2016-05-16
2016-05-17 2016-05-17
2016-05-18 2016-05-18
2016-05-19 2016-05-19
```

---

My question is: why the method `rename` does not work (in approach 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `rename` does not change the object unless you set the `inplace` argument as `True`, as seen in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rename.html).

Notice that the `copy` argument can be used so you don't have to create a new series passing the old series as argument, like in your second example.

Comment: Thanks. Another question: when doing rename(one_date), sometimes, I got the error: TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not callable but sometimes not.  For example, if I run it on my laptop, it is working well, but if I run it on a server, it will give me such TypeError. Do you have any idea why it is like this?

Comment: Out of the top of my head, it might have something to do with different versions of python libraries in those environments. You might want to check whether similar questions have been asked, and if not consider asking one about it yourself. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275094/typeerror-datetime-datetime-object-is-not-callable) question, for example, which mentions naming variables with the same name as a module as the reason.